# A lot of issues with the new eOS loki, any tip is good!

Tags: release-loki

I'm new to linux and I decided to replace my Windows 10 with elementary OS. I'm using an Asus ROG GL552VW, i7 Processor, and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M. First time when I installed it the fan was running without stopping at the maximum speed and I was able to fix that with `acpi=off`. After that I found a lot more bugs, this is a list with them, maybe you know how to fix one of them.

a) Can't shutdown the laptop, I need to force it with long press button.

b) The touchpad is not working anymore.

c) No keyboard backlights.

d) FN keys not working.

e) From time to time the screen tears.

This is how my grub file looks like!

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Was the touchpad working at some point, or is your phrasing a little off?

Answer (score 2):

Your hardware is too new.

I have read that Elementary OS' s latest ISO works "out of the box " with only the nouveau. modeset= 0 directive.

If you want to try have a look here:

https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?81702-Linux-installation-in-ASUS-ROG-GL552VW-DH71&p=563084

Comment: I was afraid of that :/

Comment: Try to update to see if bugs have been solved. There are some recent updates http://blog.elementary.io/post/150787296131/loki-release-follow-up